# Equivalent File Size methods between C# and Objective-C

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c

I'm looking at my coworker's C# code (which I'm a noob at) and seeing that he's transferring me the file size of his JSON object for me to check on the iPad end.  He does this by doing:

```
long fileSize = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName).Length;
```

I was wondering what the equivalent way to test for this is in objective-c.  I consume the data using NSURLConnection and didn't know how to check if the file size would be equivalent.  I later parse the JSON object, but I want to check if the transfer was successful by the file size.

I've tried:

```
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.ReceivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"fileSize: %i, %i", [responseString length], [responseString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

But both numbers are wrong.  I'm not sure what the right way to do this is.

Since I receive it as NSMutableData, I didn't see an easy way to check the size.  The only thing I could think of was to write the NSData to the temp or documents directory and use NSFileManager's fileSizeAtPath: method to find the file size.  Is there a better way w/o writing the file to one of the available directories?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSMutableData` inherits from `NSData`. You can use its [`length`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/length) method to get the number of bytes your data object contains. The corresponding C# method you provide is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length), which also specifies that the size is in bytes.

Comment: why would the numbers be different?  The C# size is 3245530 and the obj-c length is 11017457

Comment: @Crystal Are you checking the size of the `NSData` object or the string itself?

Comment: I have tried both, but both show 11017457.  `        NSLog(@"fileSize: %i, %i", [responseString length], [self.ReceivedData length]);`